# Getting errors while making a discord bot

Tags: python, discord, python-venv

I am fairly new to programming and trying to make my own discord bot and keep facing the following issues

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\bhati\Desktop\molectron\app.py", line 107, in 
> bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
> File "C:\Users\bhati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 860, in run
> asyncio.run(runner())
> File "C:\Users\bhati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
> return loop.run_until_complete(main)
> File "C:\Users\bhati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
> return future.result()
> File "C:\Users\bhati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 849, in runner
> await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
> File "C:\Users\bhati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 777, in start
> await self.login(token)
> File "C:\Users\bhati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 609, in login
> raise TypeError(f'expected token to be a str, received {token.**class**.**name**} instead')
> TypeError: expected token to be a str, received NoneType instead

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands,tasks
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import youtube_dl
import asyncio
load_dotenv()

# Get the API token from the .env file.
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("discord_token")
print(DISCORD_TOKEN)

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=intents)
youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''

ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0' # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)

class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)
        self.data = data
        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = ""

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))
        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]
        filename = data['title'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return filename
@bot.command(name='join', help='Tells the bot to join the voice channel')
async def join(ctx):
    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("{} is not connected to a voice channel".format(ctx.message.author.name))
        return
    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()

@bot.command(name='leave', help='To make the bot leave the voice channel')
async def leave(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_connected():
        await voice_client.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")
@bot.command(name='play_song', help='To play song')
async def play(ctx,url):
    try :
        server = ctx.message.guild
        voice_channel = server.voice_client

        async with ctx.typing():
            filename = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=bot.loop)
            voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg.exe", source=filename))
        await ctx.send('**Now playing:** {}'.format(filename))
    except:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")


@bot.command(name='pause', help='This command pauses the song')
async def pause(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_playing():
        await voice_client.pause()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not playing anything at the moment.")
    
@bot.command(name='resume', help='Resumes the song')
async def resume(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_paused():
        await voice_client.resume()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot was not playing anything before this. Use play_song command")

@bot.command(name='stop', help='Stops the song')
async def stop(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_playing():
        await voice_client.stop()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not playing anything at the moment.")
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

I tried referring to guide and documentations and could not find a solution that helped me out.
I have tried reinstalling all modules and that did not help.
Ideally the bot would have come online and responded to my commands which it did not.

Comment: Show errors and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: @MichaelButscher added it as a blockquote

Comment: It seems that the environment variable `discord_token` doesn't exist.